# Timer to close the application

Tags: c#, timer

How to make a timer which forces the application to close at a specified time in C#? I have something like this:

```
void  myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (++counter == 120)
        this.Close();
}
```

But in this case, the application will be closed in 120 sec after the timer has ran. And I need a timer, which will close the application for example at 23:00:00. Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean after 23 hours ? or after clock tick to 23

Comment: So record the time when the application was started.  Determine when the application should close.  Within a Timer thread that checks every 5 minutes, check what time it is, this will get you close to what you need.  After you get that far you can ask specific question about your code.  I won't be providing an exmaple since you have not even attempted it.

Comment: He wants to closed the program at 11pm, not after 23 hours of program runtime.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - ohh than i got wrong ..i just deleted my answer

Comment: Most of the answers aren't efficient, this will run the timer every interval and cost CPU time for nothing, Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @DorCohen - His question was specific thus the inefficient answers.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the question was general and he only gave an example.

Comment: Thank u all guys, u helped me a lot ! All answers were useful and the most important that they all were timely) The question can be closed.

Comment: @DorCohen - If thats the case then this isn't a great question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first problem you have to fix is that a System.Timers.Timer won't work.  It runs the Elapsed event handler on a thread-pool thread, such a thread cannot call the Close method of a Form or Window.  The simple workaround is to use a synchronous timer, either a System.Windows.Forms.Timer or a DispatcherTimer, it isn't clear from the question which one applies.

The only other thing you have to do is to calculate the Interval property value for the timer.  That's fairly straight-forward DateTime arithmetic.  If you always want the window to close at, say, 11 o'clock in the evening then write code like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;  // avoid race
        DateTime when = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 23, 0, 0);
        if (now > when) when = when.AddDays(1);
        timer1.Interval = (int)((when - now).TotalMilliseconds);
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify what should happen if the program is started between 2300 and midnight, but perhaps you should add `if (now > when) when.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Replaced my solution, which was based on ohadsc answer, using your one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're talking about Windows Forms here. Then this might work (**EDIT** Changed the code so `this.Invoke` is used, as we're talking about a multi-threaded timer here):

```
void  myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 23)
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate() { Close(); });
}
```

If you switch to using the Windows Forms `Timer`, then this code will work as expected:

```
void  myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 23)
        Close();
}
```

Comment: This isn't efficient, this will run the timer every interval and cost cpu time for nothing

Comment: True, but simplest based on the OP's code. Also, I leave it to you to compare the amount of time you lose executing my code (which works reliably with any given timer interval < 1 hour) every minute to the number of braincells burnt by your solution :-D

Comment: It is not only inefficient, it also won't work.  You cannot call the Close() method in a worker thread.  The exception that causes is silently swallowed, the window simply won't close.

Comment: Oh - I didn't notice that, as the OP said the code sample he provided worked. I'll fix that. I find it funny that everyonce talking about "efficiency". If I downloaded a file from a Web Server every time, then I'd be talking about efficiency - but come on...

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your request, it seems a little wasteful to have a timer check the time every second, where you can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    //If the calling context is important (for example in GUI applications)
    //you'd might want to save the Synchronization Context 
    //for example: context = SynchronizationContext.Current 
    //and use if in the lambda below e.g. s => context.Post(s => this.Close(), null)

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                s => this.Close(), null, CalcMsToHour(23, 00, 00), Timeout.Infinite);
}

int CalcMsToHour(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var due = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, minute, second);
    if (now > due)
        due.AddDays(1);
    var ms =  (due - now).TotalMilliseconds;
    return (int)ms;
}
```

Comment: Thank u, it's what i was looking for.. just to call a timer once)

Comment: So, have you tried this code? Does the window really close? Even though `this.Close()` is called within the context of a different thread?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar yup, it works. some other examples had such exception connected with thread it was called from.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Since the tagging did not imply WPF or Winforms I could not make the assumption that I'd have a `SynchronizationContext` present (theoretically `Close` could do anything)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to get the current system time. Then, see if the current time matches the time you would like your application to close at. This can be done using `DateTime` which represents an instant in time.

**Example**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(); //Initialize a new Timer of name timer1
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); //Link the Tick event with timer1_Tick
    timer1.Start(); //Start the timer
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 23 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 00 && DateTime.Now.Second == 00) //Continue if the current time is 23:00:00
    {
        Application.Exit(); //Close the whole application
        //this.Close(); //Close this form only
    }
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Thank u, this answer best suits my problem, caz i need all: hours, minutes and seconds to set.

Answer (score 3):

```
Task.Delay(9000).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    this.Close();
                }));
            }
            );
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 2):

```
void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 23)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your timer to check every second like now, but swap the contents with:

```
void  myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 23)
    this.Close();
}
```

This will make sure that when the timer run and the clock is 23:xx, then the application will shut down.