# How to exit or close the application after x second in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, time, timer, exit

Actually I found something simmilar in stackoverflow, and it didn't work for me. They wanted to exit their application in a given time (23:00). I want to exit it after 3000 second. For me the answer was helpful, now it's working, the main point, that it's important, where you put this code in your programme.

This code is managing a multi beam RFID reader to localizate the Tags. It will give you the x and y coordinates ( and some other informations - EPC, Timestamp, the report type, etc). Actually the program works properly, but I would like to run it just for 5 minutes. I'm measuring the accuracy of the Reader, with different set up and it would be more comparable if all of my measurements would be 3000 sec ( or whatever) . Now the program exit if I hit the enter.

I was searching and trying a lot, but it doesn't want to work for me. I hope somebody can help here.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Impinj.OctaneSdk;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace OctaneSdkExamples
{
    class Program
    {

        // Create an instance of the ImpinjReader class.
        static ImpinjReader reader = new ImpinjReader();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Connect to the reader.
                // Change the ReaderHostname constant in SolutionConstants.cs 
                // to the IP address or hostname of your reader.
                reader.Connect(SolutionConstants.ReaderHostname);

                // Assign the LocationReported event handler.
                // This specifies which method to call
                // when a location report is available.
                reader.LocationReported += OnLocationReported;

                // Get the default settings
                // We'll use these as a starting point
                // and then modify the settings we're 
                // interested in.
                Settings settings = reader.QueryDefaultSettings();

                // Put the xArray into location mode
                settings.SpatialConfig.Mode = SpatialMode.Location;

                // Enable all three report types
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.EntryReportEnabled = true;
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.UpdateReportEnabled = true;
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.ExitReportEnabled = true;

                // Set xArray placement parameters

                // The mounting height of the xArray, in centimeters
                settings.SpatialConfig.Placement.HeightCm = 100
                    ;
                // These settings aren't required in a single xArray environment
                // They can be set to zero (which is the default)
                settings.SpatialConfig.Placement.FacilityXLocationCm = 0;
                settings.SpatialConfig.Placement.FacilityYLocationCm = 0;
                settings.SpatialConfig.Placement.OrientationDegrees = 0;

                // Set xArray location parameters
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.ComputeWindowSeconds = 10;
                settings.ReaderMode = ReaderMode.AutoSetDenseReader;
                settings.Session = 2;
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.TagAgeIntervalSeconds = 20;

                // Specify how often we want to receive location reports
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.UpdateIntervalSeconds = 5;

                // Set this to true if the maximum transmit power is desired, false if a custom value is desired
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.MaxTxPower = false;

                // If MaxTxPower is set to false, then a custom power can be used. Provide a power in .25 dBm increments
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.TxPowerInDbm = 23.00;

                // Disable antennas targeting areas from which we may not want location reports,
                // in this case we're disabling antennas 10 and 15
                List<ushort> disabledAntennas = new List<ushort> { };
                settings.SpatialConfig.Location.DisabledAntennaList = disabledAntennas;

                // Uncomment this is you want to filter tags
                /*
                // Setup a tag filter.
                // Only the tags that match this filter will respond.
                // We want to apply the filter to the EPC memory bank.
                settings.Filters.TagFilter1.MemoryBank = MemoryBank.Epc;
                // Start matching at the third word (bit 32), since the 
                // first two words of the EPC memory bank are the
                // CRC and control bits. BitPointers.Epc is a helper
                // enumeration you can use, so you don't have to remember this.
                settings.Filters.TagFilter1.BitPointer = BitPointers.Epc;
                // Only match tags with EPCs that start with "3008"
                settings.Filters.TagFilter1.TagMask = "3008";
                // This filter is 16 bits long (one word).
                settings.Filters.TagFilter1.BitCount = 16;

                // Set the filter mode. Use only the first filter
                settings.Filters.Mode = TagFilterMode.OnlyFilter1;
                */

                // Apply the newly modified settings.
                reader.ApplySettings(settings);

                // Start the reader
                reader.Start();

                timer1_Tick(3000);

                // Wait for the user to press enter.
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Apply the default settings before exiting.
                reader.ApplyDefaultSettings();

                // Disconnect from the reader.
                reader.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (OctaneSdkException e)
            {
                // Handle Octane SDK errors.
                Console.WriteLine("Octane SDK exception: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle other .NET errors.
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        // This event handler will be called when a location report is ready.
        static void OnLocationReported(ImpinjReader reader, LocationReport report)
        {
            // Print out the report details
            Console.WriteLine("Location report");
            Console.WriteLine("   Type = {0}", report.ReportType);
            Console.WriteLine("   EPC = {0}", report.Epc);
            Console.WriteLine("   X = {0} cm", report.LocationXCm);
            Console.WriteLine("   Y = {0} cm", report.LocationYCm);
            Console.WriteLine("   Timestamp = {0} ({1})", report.Timestamp, report.Timestamp.LocalDateTime);
            Console.WriteLine("   Read count = {0}", report.ConfidenceFactors.ReadCount);

            // Saving data
            string path = @"b:\Master Thesis\xArray\Tests\Test 3 - Height-100cm, Disabled Antennas - , TxPowerInDbm-23.25, UpdateIntervalSeconds-5, ComputeWindowSeconds-10, ReaderMode_AutoSetDenseReader, TagAgeIntervalSeconds-20, tags 40 cm from origo .txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Type, Epc, X Localization, Y localization, Timestamp, Local Date Time, Read Count ");
                    // This text is added only once to the file.
                }
            }

            // This text is always added, making the file longer over time

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("   {0} , {1} , {2} , {3} , {4} , {5} , {6}    ", report.ReportType, report.Epc, report.LocationXCm, report.LocationYCm, report.Timestamp, report.Timestamp.LocalDateTime, report.ConfidenceFactors.ReadCount);

            }
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reader.Disconnect(); 
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Well `Console.ReadLine();` is what's keeping the program open as it expects input, why is it there if you want it to close?

Comment: Recommend posting a minimum complete verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timer to close the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626454/timer-to-close-the-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your application to close after just 5 minutes you can do this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(300000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    }

    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: But instead of `Application.Exit` I should use `Enviroment.Exit`

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is how to end a console application in a timer event handler.  How about `Environment.Exit(0)`.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;timer.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with this code, it's not doing anything, just open the console, wait 10 s and exiting. Then I changed that for the other solutions (can be found below). And it's working....